# Gnome 3 finger gestures not working well when tap to click is enabled

Tags: linux, fedora, gnome, wayland

I've just switched to fedora (fedora 35) and i noticed that when i enable the tap to click, three finger gestures not working well. If i disable it the gestures work just fine but if i enable it the sensitivity is not as good, i have to do the gestures very slowly for gnome to pick up. So what is the reason for this and is there a solution?

PS. My pc is Lenovo Thikpad E495 and i have windows 10 installed on my computer besides fedora.

Comment: What touchpad do you have?

Comment: My pc is lenovo thinkpad e495.